# How to change default checkbox values in a form when there are multiple checkboxes

Tags: php, html, forms, email, checkbox

I have a form with 4 checkboxes. When the boxes are checked, the email generated from the form displays the default 'on', for each checkbox that is checked.

I wanted to change this to 'Yes'. The problem is that although I can change the default to 'Yes' using the code below, 'Yes' now appears next to every option in the email, whether the checkboxes were checked on the form or not. I am new to PHP and so far none of the answers I've searched address the problem I'm having. Any suggestions on how to fix would be much appreciated. Thanks!

The HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="red" id="red" value="yes">
  <label for="red">Red</label></p><p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="blue" id="blue" value="yes">
  <label for="blue">Blue</label></p><p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="green" id="green" value="yes">
  <label for="green">Green</label></p><p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="yellow" id="yellow" value="yes">
  <label for="yellow">Yellow</label>
```

The PHP

```
    $red = $_POST['red'];
if ($red != 'Yes') {
    $red = 'Yes';
}

$blue = $_POST['blue'];
if ($blue != 'Yes') {
    $blue = 'Yes';
}
$green = $_POST['green'];
if ($green != 'Yes') {
    $green = 'Yes';
}

$yellow = $_POST['yellow'];
if ($yellow != 'Yes') {
    $yellow = 'Yes';
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You have an error in your logic. Your code says "if the value is not equal to 'Yes' then set it to 'Yes'". This means if the value is 'off' it is turned to 'Yes' because 'off' is not equal to 'Yes'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oc all will be displayed as yes, whay you are doing is por every checkbox checking if it is not yes then set to yes. Your final result will be all boxes set to yes. Try this:

```
$red = $_POST['red'];
if ($red != 'Yes') {
    $red == 'No';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you check the checkbox then only it will  be  available via `$_POST` so

```
$red = $_POST['red'];
if ($red != 'Yes') {
    $red = 'Yes';
}
```

will set it $red to Yes whether or not you check the checkbox as `$red = $_POST['red'];` will return null 
and  `$_POST['red'];` will give you the value attribute of the input:checkbox `<input type="checkbox" name="red" id="red" value="yes">` in this case it will output `yes`.